# SELECT keyword in LINQ and sql

Tags: linq

Why SELECT keyword is at the end in LINQ queries

```
from m in myClass1 
where m.myfield == value 
select m
```

whereas its at the begining in SQL queries?

```
select * from myTable
```

Comment: Not all sql queries start with `SELECT`, i often use [common-table-expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) in T-SQL: `WITH CTE AS(SomeQueries) 
SELECT A,B,C FROM CTE...`.

Answer (score 7):

So that you can get IntelliSense in the `select` clause.

This way, when you start typing `select`, the compiler already knows the types involved in the query.

It also reads more naturally; the selecting is the last step of any query.

Comment: Upvoted, as this shows that there's some logic behind why they decided to design it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Because that is how the designers designed it. LINQ isn't SQL.

It also helps the query format follow the same flow as the lambda:

```
myClass1.Where(m.myfield == value).Select(m => m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because these are two different languages: although it appears that C# and VB.NET language designers looked at SQL's keywords to borrow semantics, they did not take the syntax "wholesale", because of the need to fit the syntax into the language around LINQ.

Note that the syntax that they chose is friendly for auto-completion tools: the name of the class is known at the time when you write your `select`, letting Visual Studio offer you auto-completions for the properties of `myClass`.